How do I add blurring effect to ListWheelScrollView in Flutter?
This is my ListWheelScrollView:
ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
                    overAndUnderCenterOpacity: 0.2,
                    controller: scrollController,
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemExtent: 50,
                    perspective: 0.003,
                    diameterRatio: 1.5,
                    childDelegate: ListWheelChildLoopingListDelegate(
                      children: dateIdeas.map((idea) {
                        return Center(
                          child: Text(
                            idea,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 24,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  );

I'm trying to figure out how I can add a blurring effect to the text that's over and under the center item.
I've tried using a ImageFiltered widget on the text but that obviously blurs all items in the list. I'm not sure how I would apply this to just the top and bottom items.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

The solution could be blur the entire area about and below the box instead of the items
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(const ScrollApp());
}

class ScrollApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScrollApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Scroll'),
        ),
        body: const ScrollWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScrollWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 300.0,
      child: ScrollBlur(
        centerHeight: 50.0,
        child: ListWheelScrollView(
          overAndUnderCenterOpacity: 0.5,
          itemExtent: 50,
          diameterRatio: 1.5,
          children: [
            for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++)
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "idea $index",
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollBlur extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScrollBlur({super.key, required this.centerHeight, required this.child});
  final double centerHeight;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        child,
        ClipPath(
          clipper: MyClipper(
            centerHeight: centerHeight,
          ),
          child: BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3, sigmaY: 3),
            child: const SizedBox.expand(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  const MyClipper({required this.centerHeight});
  final double centerHeight;

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final double centerStart = size.height / 2 - centerHeight / 2;
    final double centerEnd = size.height / 2 + centerHeight / 2;
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(0.0, 0.0)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0.0)
      ..lineTo(size.width, centerStart)
      ..lineTo(0.0, centerStart)
      ..close()
      ..moveTo(0.0, centerEnd)
      ..lineTo(size.width, centerEnd)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(0.0, size.height)
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}

There is a bug in ListWheelScrollView #96427 that prevent child with filter to be rendered correctly. So the filter couldn't be apply to the item directly.
